# Replace the value 0.00 in a Python array with a text character

Tags: python

I am downloading a large data file from the Internet and I want to convert the values '0.00' in one column to a text character 'C'.

```
i= np.loadtxt('first_simple.txt')
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
i=np.asarray(i,str)
np.place(i,i=='0.00','C')
print(i)
```

I think the data is initially floats.

I got an error message at first to do with the data type, so I converted the data to strings, but now Python just hangs.

I think there must be a better way of doing this task.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code worked after making an alteration:

```
np.place(i,i=='0.00','C')
to 
np.place(i,i=='0.0','C')
```

When I changed the datatype to a string, it removed a 0 which meant the place command did not find a '0.00' string.

My code works, but it is very slow.

If there's a better solution, can you let me know?

Thank you.